# Trouble deploying Rails app with Capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, vps

I've been building my first Rails app and now I'm trying to deploy it, and I've been following [these instructions](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/06/28/setup-a-ubuntu-vps-for-hosting-ruby-on-rails-applications-2/), which have worked great up to the point where it tells me to run `cap deploy:setup`, because I get this message back:

```
[err :: my.vps.ip.address] bash: /root/.rvm/bin/rvm-shell: No such file or directory

failed: "rvm_path=$HOME/.rvm/ $HOME/.rvm/bin/rvm-shell 'default' -c 'mkdir -p var/rails/test_app/current var/rails/test_app/current/releases var/rails/test_app/current/shared var/rails/test_app/current/shared/system var/rails/test_app/current/shared/log var/rails/test_app/current/shared/pids'" on my.vps.ip.address
```

and I've looked around trying to find a solution to the problem, and I've tried a few of them with no success, and in all honesty I simply don't understand what any of what that error means, so I'd be grateful if anyone could help, or even just explain to me what it's telling me.

If there's any other info I need to provide, please let me know, I'm sure there is and I'm just not aware.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to login to the server as root.  Did you setup another user on the server?  Also, check your capistrano deploy.rb for the user info.

Comment: That's right - is it a mistake to log in as root? I haven't set up another user as far as I know...

Comment: As standard practice, I generally create a normal user "rails" that I use for deploying my apps.  The reason you'll need to create a different user (as the author describes in the tutorial you're following) is that the permissions and PATH changes when you're logged in as root.

Comment: OK - I've just created a new user (I went with 'rails' per your suggestion), and I'm getting the same error but with '/home/' where previously it was '/root/' - what is the PATH? Where is that set?